# Formatting Date to get last two digits from year number (ex: 19 from 2019)

Tags: java, string, date, calendar, formatting

I have that code.

```
Calendar data = Calendar.getInstance();
data.setTime(new Date());
System.out.println(String.valueOf(data.get(Calendar.YEAR)).substring(2,4));
```

I have 2 issues:
First, I need to have it in a single `String` (to put it into `sout`). Is it possible?
Second, I have to use date formatting instead of transformation into string. For example to get `"19"` instead of `"2019"`.

Comment: You can use a StringBuilder to build up all the tokens you need into a single string. `Stringbuilder mStringBuilder = new Stringbuilder();`

Comment: Could you please show us the desired output? I mean the full one, not just the last two digits of the year.

Comment: The `Calendar` class is poorly designed and long outdated. Don't use it. Use `LocalDate` and `DateTimeFormatter`, both from java.time, the modern Java date and tme API.

Answer (score 5):

Use `LocalDate` with a custom formatting pattern in a `DateTimeFormatter` object.

```
LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.now();

System.out.println("Full date --> "+DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyy/MM/dd").format(localDate));
System.out.println("Just Year --> "+DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yy").format(localDate));
```

Comment: Plus a tip: Pass a time zone `ZoneId` in that call to `now`. For any given moment, the date varies around the globe by zone. If omitted, the JVM’s current default time zone is implicitly used. Better to explicitly specify your desired/expected zone.

Comment: Thanks. But what if i need to use already existing custom date in Date format? How can i use it in LocalDate constructor?

Answer (score 3):

## tl;dr

```
Integer                                       // Class for dealing with 32-bit integer numbers.
.parseInt(                                    // Parses text into an `int` primitive value.
    Year                                      // Class representing an entire year.
    .now(                                     // Captures the current year as seen through the wall-clock time of a particular region (a time zone).
        ZoneId.of( "Africa/Tunis" )           // Time zone required to determine the current year, as the date varies for any given moment around the globe by zone.
    )                                         // Returns a `Year` object (not a number). 
    .format(                                  // Generate text representing the value of our `Year` object.
        DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "uu" )   // Custom formatting pattern of `uu` means the year number without the century.
    )                                         // Returns a `String`. 
)                                             // Returns an `int` primitive.
```

See this code run live at IdeOne.com.

> 19

## `Year`

If you are working with years as a specific entity, use the `Year` class. Then you can use objects rather than mere integers. This makes your code more [self-documenting](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-documenting_code), and provides [type safety](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_safety).

Capture the current year.

```
Year year = Year() ;
```

Understand that capturing the current date, and year, requires a time zone. For any given moment, the date varies around the globe by zone.

If omitted, the JVM’s current time zone is automatically applied. That default can be changed at any moment by any code running within the JVM. So better to specify explicitly your desired/expected zone.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) ; 
Year year = Year.now( z ) ;
```

Generate text by calling `format`, passing a `DateTimeFormatter` with a custom formatting pattern.

```
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "uu" ) ;
String output = year.format( f ) ;
```

You can make an integer of that text if needed.

```
int yearNumberWithoutCentury = Integer.parseInt( output ) ;
```

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/DgJRg2).

> year.toString(): 2019
>
> output: 19
>
> yearNumberWithoutCentury: 19

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Answer (score 2):

Get the current moment and format it using [**java.time**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html)
(possible in Java 8 and higher or by using a [backport for Java 6 and 7](https://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/)):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // get the instant in a local date time (no time zone or offset information)
    LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now();
    // format it as desired
    System.out.println(now.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd.MM.yy HH:mm:ss")));
    // or just the date
    System.out.println(now.toLocalDate().format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yy")));
}
```

Output:

```
25.11.19 13:10:35
25/11/19
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just get the Year and then get the reminder of a division by 100:

```
Calendar data = Calendar.getInstance();
data.setTime(new Date());
System.out.println(data.get(Calendar.YEAR) % 100);
```

Comment: This will not always give two digits. For years from 2000 through 2009, for example, only one digit (and we should not use `Calendar`).